# Error after incomplete upgrade from ubuntu14.04 to 16.04 -- Kernel panic, not syncing: Attempted to kill init: exit code = 0x00007f00

Tags: linux-kernel, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-10.04

I was in the progress of upgrading my ubuntu system from 14.04 to 16.06 using the GUI software updater.My battery died and machine went off. When I tried to restart,I get this error below.

```
run-init: /sbin/init: No such file or directory
Target file system does not have requested /sbin/init
run-init: /sbin/init: No such file or directory
run-init: /etc/init: Permission denied
run-init: /bin/init: No such file or directory
/bin/sh O: Can'topen splash
[5.210492] Kernel panic, not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00007f00
kernel offset 0x0 from 0xffffffff8100000000
drm_kms_helper: panic occured, switching back to text console
```

At this point it stays in this black screen till I restart, and it happens like this again.

I searched on other forums and I was advised to download and run the bootinfoscript. I run it and had results in a text file but I am unable to attach it here (more than 30000 characters)

Kindly help me resolve this. I don't want to reinstall as I have too much to lose.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have access to a command line?  Try using a TTY (CTRL + ALT + 2) to get command line access if your stuck.  Then try just re-doing your upgrade again with `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and `sudo do-release-upgrade`.

Note that if you do need to re-install, you can always do it on another disk, then mount and copy data off of your previous disk whenever it's convenient.  This is why I like to have my `/home/` mounted on a different disk/partition.

Comment: i cannot access command line.. i went to advanced ubuntu options to try using other kernel versions, but none of them works...